# Android keyboard rotation

Tags: android, keyboard, rotation

Is it possible to disable orientation changes for an activity but still be able to rotate the keyboard?

I would like to be able to write text in landscape mode but keep the activity mode fixed in portrait mode.

Comment: maybe look into android:configChanges = "keyboard|orientation" in manifest and then override public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) in activity, im not really sure but it sounds like it would be the ticket along those lines